# Use numpy in script class (torch.jit.script)

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, jit

I was wondering if I can use numpy APIs in a function which is going to be scripted by `torch.jit.script`. I have this simple function which does not work:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class MyModule(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super(MyModule, self).__init__()

@torch.jit.ignore
def call_np():
    return torch.jit.export(np.random.choice(2, p=[.95,.05]))

def forward(self):
    pass 

@torch.jit.export
def func(self):
    done = self.call_np()
    print (done)
```

> scripted_module = torch.jit.script(MyModule())
>   scripted_module.func()

which results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-ab1ce37d6edc> in <module>()
     18         print (done)
     19 
---> 20 scripted_module = torch.jit.script(MyModule())
     21 scripted_module.func()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py in script(obj, optimize, _frames_up, _rcb)
   1201 
   1202     if isinstance(obj, torch.nn.Module):
-> 1203         return torch.jit.torch.jit._recursive.recursive_script(obj)
   1204 
   1205     qualified_name = _qualified_name(obj)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_recursive.py in recursive_script(mod, exclude_methods)
    171     filtered_methods = filter(ignore_overloaded, methods)
    172     stubs = list(map(make_stub, filtered_methods))
--> 173     return copy_to_script_module(mod, overload_stubs + stubs)
    174 
    175 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_recursive.py in copy_to_script_module(original, stubs)
     93             setattr(script_module, name, item)
     94 
---> 95     torch.jit._create_methods_from_stubs(script_module, stubs)
     96 
     97     # Now that methods have been compiled, take methods that have been compiled

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py in _create_methods_from_stubs(self, stubs)
   1421     rcbs = [m.resolution_callback for m in stubs]
   1422     defaults = [get_default_args(m.original_method) for m in stubs]
-> 1423     self._c._create_methods(self, defs, rcbs, defaults)
   1424 
   1425 # For each user-defined class that subclasses ScriptModule this meta-class,

RuntimeError: Unable to cast Python instance of type <class 'int'> to C++ type 'unsigned __int64'
```

I appreciate any help or comment.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answered at the pytorch forum:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/use-numpy-in-script-class-torch-jit-script/62351